# What role does $i$ play when we use complex coordinates?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, riemann-surfaces

When we consider $\mathbb R^2$ but use the complex coordinate $z=x+iy,\bar z=x-iy$, why does $i$ behave like a scalar?

The background is that, simply from the definition of a complex coordinate that $i$ is nothing but a symbol. However, in actual computations the $i$ behaves like a number with nice properties.

I had this problem when I was trying to show
$$dz\otimes d\bar z=dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy$$
By definition,
$$dz\otimes d\bar z=(dx+idy)\otimes(dx-idy)\\
=dx\otimes dx+dx\otimes(idy)-dx\otimes (idy)-(idy)\otimes(idy)\\
=dx\otimes dx+idx\otimes dy-idx\otimes idy-i^2dy\otimes dy
\\=dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy\\
$$
But wait, in the third line $i$ is moved to the front of the tensor, i.e. behaves like a scalar. However, these tensors belong to a vector field over $\mathbb R$. And $i$ is not real, hence I don't see a reason allowing us to move $i$ outside.

So what is the justification for this?

Comment: You mentioned “**the** definition” of $i$ (emphasis mine), as if there was only one definition. Which definition do you have in mind?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSanto You incorrectly parsed my sentence. I've edited to avoid confusion.

Comment: Are you sure the tensor product is not over $\mathbf C$?

Comment: @Bernard Actually I am not. The way I see it, suppose we first work without the complex coordinate, then any tensor product is surely over $\mathbb R$. Usually at this point, an author would say, "let's represent this in the complex coordinate!" and then write what I wrote above. I mean if we are just changing coordinates, the field of scalars shouldn't change at all. But if somehow the complex coordinate is so special that all of this works, I'd like an explanation why. That's what I am asking here.